# MYSQL string replace on column PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace

Hi i want to do the equivalent of a string replace in php through mysql. My column has the string format "Release Date: Thursday 20th May 2012" I want to release the text release date:. I have tried this but with no avail

```
$query = ("UPDATE Films SET Film_Release = REPLACE(Film_Release, 'Release Date: ','"); 

$runquery = mysql_query($query);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe because of the typo's? Try this `$query = "UPDATE Films SET Film_Release = REPLACE(Film_Release, 'Release Date: ','')";`

Comment: looks like you're missing apostrophe at the end where you're specifying the replacement string

Comment: what WouterH said. You're missing the second apostrophe of the replacement string and the closing bracket of the MySQL REPLACE function

Answer (score 2):

Try with an extra `'` and with a closing `)`

```
$query = "UPDATE Films SET Film_Release = REPLACE(Film_Release, 'Release Date: ','')";
```

Comment: what a perfect copy/paste of my comment :)